# Internet appears to randomly go out, with DNS lookups and connections to sites by IP failing, but online games still work

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

My internet seems to intermittently go out on my wifi connection. This seems to happen randomly. It only affects my Windows 10 desktop (which has all the latest updates) and not any other device on the same network. At first I thought it might have been a DNS issue (using Google's DNS), but I cannot even access sites by their IP address. Yet, the game overwatch can continue playing matches fine (although it cannot join new games in this state).

I've replaced the wifi adaptor with the problem persisting and drivers are up to date. Using the Realtek USB Wireless LAN utility that came with the adaptor, renewing the IP address makes the problem temporarily go away (as does restarting the computer). Running `nslookup` fails for any domain.

Perhaps worth noting that I don't really have access to the router.

What might be done to diagnose or correct this issue?

Comment: Sometimes wifi problems are just down to signal quality. If your wifi connection is a USB dongle, and you have a USB extender cable, try moving it well away from the case, especially fans and the power supply, away from the monitor, etc.

Comment: I don't think it's down to signal quality. I've got a strong signal and other devices (which I'd expect have a smaller antenna) perform fine. I'm also really starting to suspect something weird about Overwatch because this occurs the most when running that.